# Heroku ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.1.7

I have a module inside lib/ directory.

lib/BLL/user_feed.rb

```
module BLL
 class UserFeed

    def initialize
        logger.debug "Class has been initialized"
    end

    def get_user_feed(user_id)
      # logic here

        return {
         # object
        }
    end
 end
end
```

When I try to include that in my controller to use my user_Feed logic,

```
 class UserfeedController < ApplicationController
  include BLL

 before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
   # some logic
  end
end
```

In my config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

**This runs fine locally, however, it breaks when I deploy it on Heroku.**

it's throwing

**ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserfeedController::BLL):**

error.

```
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791457+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/api/v1/userfeed_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bll (NameError)
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791458+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791459+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791460+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791462+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2015-10-20T13:45:13.791463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Try to rename a folder to lowercase (`BLL` ⇒ `bll`) and (unlikely, the former should help) `include ::BLL`.

Comment: yes, that's how I have it. lowercae bll

Comment: see my latest answer; may be this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails in fact loads your app directory when the app loads. So actually no need to mention your **app/bll** in autoload paths.

However, what I am doing wrong here in this case is adding module on top of the class.

So, my app is looking for app/bll/bll/Whatever

```
module Bll - there is not need for this module to be declared
  class Whatever
    # some logic.
  end
end
```

All you need to do is.

```
 class Whatever

 end
```

After this, your class is available to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `module BLL; end` in `lib/bll.rb`

But also, play with naming the module `Bll`, but I don't think that's it

Comment: please look @ the edits above, I added error info for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/BLL)
```

and dont forget to restart the server

**Edit1**
Moreover; changing the name of Dir `BLL` to `bll` also works

Comment: Answer is Once edited; make sure you watched the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Ruby defaults to [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), you'll have to use the following:

```
#vendor/bll/user_feed.rb
module Bll
  class UserFeed
    ...
  end
end
```

As a second, the `vendor` dir is autoloaded (to the best of my knowledge), so the above code *should* work to fix the `UnrecognizedConstant` error.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-lib-and-vendor-folders